# Hitting OBIEE presentation Server URL with Java

Tags: java, http, http-headers, obiee

I am trying to impersonate one user in OBIEE Server, which is working fine in browser.
URL:
***http://SRVR:port/analytics/saw.dll?Dashboard&NQUser=Admin&NQPassword=AdminPasswd&Impersonate=impersonateUser***

I am hitting that URL with Java to get some response from server but getting Error:
**HTTP code is 200 &
Your browser is not supported by Oracle BI Presentation Services**

Java code

```
>Client client = Client.create();
>WebResource webResource =
> client.resource("http://SRVR:port/analytics/saw.dll?Dashboard&NQUser=Admin&NQPassword=AdminPasswd&Impersonate=impersonateUser");
>           ClientResponse response =
> webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
>           System.out.println(response.getStatus());
>           System.out.println(ClientResponse.Status.fromStatusCode(response.getStatus()));
>           String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
>               System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
>               System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

So it is confirming existence of the resource, but requires a browser. Or you can trick into thinking the request was originating from within a browser.

You may need to dissect what is happening in:
webResource.accept().get() 
Then, retrieve the full GET request when originated from the browser. Spoof how it is constructed in your web service call.

Also, have you considered using the [GO URL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/bi.1111/e16364/apiwebintegrate.htm#BIEIT353)?

Comment: I have used SOAP Client, Create in Java. It's working fine. I faced problem handling SSL Certificate that also handled by Jersey Bundle. <br>Problem is solved.<br> Thanks a lot